# Desktop icons appear over windows when unlocking screen

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, 22.04, mutter

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.1 with the following specifications:

**CPU:** Intel i7-7700HQ
**GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile (With nvidia-driver-525)
**RAM:** 16GB
**Kernel:** 5.15.0-60-generic
**DE:** GNOME
**WM:** Mutter
**Display server:** Xorg

All packages have been updated to latest available versions as of 2023/02/13. Occasionally, when I unlock the system from a suspend or screen lock, the desktop icons are displayed over all opened windows, and I am unable to select any open window until I manually Alt+TAB through them. What could be the cause of this issue? Any troubleshooting assistance would be highly welcome. I have not found a method of consistently reproducing this problem.

Edit: I have attached a screenshot of an open firefox window after waking up from suspend.
[Desktop icons displayed over open window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEAkE.png)

Comment: Same problem. Latitude E6330, i3 CPU, builtin Intel CPU GPU, 8Gb RAM, 5.19.0-38-generic, default Gnome session. Ubuntu 22.04